# ripple effect is showing on non-clickable button which is inside a clickable card

Tags: android, android-layout, material-ui

I have set button property `clickable="false"` which inside a card, which has a property `clickable=true` and `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`, but when I click on card the button is also showing ripple effect. Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/payment_card_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="4dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/monthlySubscriptionPayButton"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:text="@string/payment_pay_text"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/junkart_color"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:clickable="false"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set `clickable="true"` and `foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` value in LinearLayout inside CardView and your problem will be solved.

Refer below **changes** I've made in your code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/payment_card_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#fff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/monthlySubscriptionPayButton"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:text="@string/payment_pay_text"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/junkart_color"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:clickable="false"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Hope it helps to you. Let me know if it is solved.

Comment: That doesn't help, I want click event and ripple on whole card and some of my button @+id/monthlySubscriptionPayButton will be non-clickable and for those I don't want ripple effect. your answer also shows ripple effect on non-clickable button when parent linearlayout touched.

Answer (score 1):

A solution might be setting the button to disabled (`setEnabled(false)`) next to being not clickable. Although this might not be an option if the style is different for disabled buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Set clickable attribute false on CardView. If parent view is clickable drawable state change event will dispatch to child view, no matter child view is clickable or not.